# How to get the logged on user/users of a windows server?

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

for desktops I use the win32_computersystem wmi class and just read "username", but this is blank on windows servers.

Also, there can be only one active session on a client where as a server can have multiple people logged in- assuming this is part of the reason why I can't get it with the same class.

How do I get the currently logged in user/users of a server?

Comment: `quser /server:MyServer1` might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$computer = 'MyServer1'
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process -computer $computer -Filter 'name = "explorer.exe"' | % {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
get-process -computer $computer explorer | % {$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}
```

or perhaps this

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LastLogon-Determining-283f98ae